# A book about a professor that returns to university in a little town and people, possibly animals, die from poisoning

Tags: identification-request

My brother wrote to me that he's looking for a book that he read some years ago. Since I don't seem to know it, I thought you might help me.

It's about a professor who returns to a university in a little village in the United States. People die, and also animals (a certain kind of birds I think) because of poisoning. In the end the main character gets kidnapped and is held on an isolated private reservation (by native Americans?).

I don't remember ever having heard of such a book.

Comment: I've never read the book. I just have a suggestion which might help you. I've heard that an author named Tony Hillerman wrote a whole series of popular mystery novels set on and around an Indian reservation. I never really got into them, but it's at least possible that one of them had a plot such as you describe.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Literature. Please make sure you've checked out the [tour], read [ask] (and possibly [answer]), as well as the [Story-ID guidelines](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info). What language did he read it in? Where was he when he read it? Medium? Etc. I hope you decide to stick around!

Comment: @Luca You seem to have created two separate accounts (the one you used to ask this question and the one you used to place a bounty on it). If this was by accident, [please see the instructions for merging your accounts](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). With a single account you'll be able to edit your own question more easily, and to accept an answer if someone finds the story for you.